# node js plist creation issue

Tags: node.js, plist

I am creating a plist from node js. Converting entire request body to plist. But when a '&' is coming inside the request json. The plist conversion is faling. How can I solve this issue. I tried with a sting replacement
`var msg = request.body; msg.replace("&", "&amp;");`

But is it a good way to solve it.

Comment: How are you making a plist? Can you post the string you are trying to convert.

Comment: I am using a plist lib from github.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>params</key>
    <dict>
      <key>param1</key>
      <data>SMS & sms</data>
      <key>param2</key>
      <data>MMS & mms</data>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: I know it's basically a year later since this was posted. But I've had issues with the base64 encoding/decoding in this module. I modified it to turn off base64 decoding. I'm gonna guess that it sees this &amp and decides to try to base64 decode the <data> tag.